# how to conditionally fill cell color based on value from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Been scrolling here for days and haven't found any answers useful to my case. I have an excel file and I created a column that gives a 0 or a 1. What I want is to color the corresponding row yellow if the cell value is 1.

I haven't had much success. Please help! Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_excel('genrep 2022-10-11.xlsx')

trylist= df['try list'].tolist()

for i in trylist:
    def highlight_cells(i):
        return 'background-color: yellow' if i==1 else ''

df.style.applymap(highlight_cells, subset = ['Org ID Owner', 'Uploaded By'])
print(df.style)
file = "C:\\Users\\U6085771\\Desktop\\try.xlsx"

df.style.to_excel('try.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
os.startfile(file)
```

Meanwhile here are a few rows from my dataset

```
|  Uploaded By | Org ID Owner  | try list  
0|                                  NaN |       Felix   |      0  
1|               www_ftp_weblink_com_au |       Junya   |      0  
2|                          TS\Felix.Sy |       Nisha   |      0  
3|                          TS\Felix.Sy |       Felix   |      1  
4|                          TS\Felix.Sy |       Felix   |      1  
5|                          TS\Felix.Sy |       Felix   |      1  
6|                          ESG_Sparrow |     Abhinav   |      0  
7|                      Jose Bienvenido |         Job   |      1  
8|                          TS\Felix.Sy |       Felix   |      1  
9|                          ESG_Sparrow |   Shafaqhat   |      0
```

Edit: I revised my code (thank u @chris!) and it worked like a charm!

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_excel('genrep 2022-10-11.xlsx')

df = df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: #FFFF00", 
                  subset=(df["try list"].eq(1), df.columns))

file = "C:\\Users\\U6085771\\Desktop\\try.xlsx"
df.style.to_excel('try.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
os.startfile(file)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataset so others can reproduce the same result. You can copy paste `print(df.head(10))` or so

Comment: hello! Sorry this sounds dumb but how do I share a copy of my dataset? :)

Comment: Right after the `pd.read_excel`, add `print(df.head(10))`, which will print first 10 rows of your data. You can copy paste that into your question. Remember it is extremely hard for answerers to reproduce your dataset (and thereby code that works on your data) just by looking at the image.

Comment: okay please hold, let me try doing that on pycharm :)

Comment: sorry that took so long, I had a hard time figuring it out! :) but it's posted now!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to clearly set your `subset`.

Note that `subset` must be compatible with `df.loc`, meaning that you can test your conditions by `df.loc`.

> subset : label, array-like, IndexSlice, optional
> A valid 2d input to `DataFrame.loc[<subset>]`, or, in the case of a 1d input
> or single key, to `DataFrame.loc[:, <subset>]` where the columns are
> prioritised, to limit `data` to *before* applying the function.

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: yellow", 
                  subset=(df["try list"].eq(1), df.columns))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Chris! Thanks for taking the time to respond :) May I know if you have links to existing documentation on this? I’m trying to understand .eq(1) and why df.columns appears next to it, but I don’t want to hassle you any further than I have. Once again thank you for your time :)

Comment: @mpong It means that the styling must be applied to `subset=<row_conditions, column_conditions>`. Hence `row_conditions == df["try list"].eq(1)`, so all rows where `try list` is zero + `columns_conditions == df.columns` which means all columns of above rows

Comment: import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_excel('genrep 2022-10-11.xlsx')

df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: yellow", 
                  subset=(df["try list"].eq(1), df.columns))

file = "C:\\Users\\U6085771\\Desktop\\try.xlsx"
df.style.to_excel('try.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
os.startfile(file)

Hello! I don't know why it's still not working :(

Comment: @mpong add `df=df.style.applymap(...)` since it is not a inplace operation.